# Webpack: Static Site Generator Plugin Error: ERROR in ReferenceError: self is not defined

Tags: webpack, plugins

I am attempting a project that uses Webpack. I've added the plugins Mini CSS Extract and Static Site Generator. My code works when I have the snippets for the Static Site Generator removed (although the HTML doesn't render, for obvious reasons.)

My Webpack config file

```
    const path = require('path')
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
    const StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-webpack-plugin');

    const locals = {
        routes: [
            '/',
        ]
    };


    module.exports = {
        mode: "development",
        entry: './src',

        output: {
            libraryTarget: "umd",
            path:path.resolve(__dirname,'build'),
            filename: 'bundle.js',
        },

        plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {filename: "build/[name].css"}
        ), 
//Giving me the error when I have it here
new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin({
            paths: [
                '/',
            ],
            locals: {
                greet: 'Hello'
            }
        })],

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src')
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"]
                },
                 
            ],

        }
    };
```

This is my index.js file that I'm trying to get to render

```
module.exports = function render(locals, callback) {
    callback(null, '<html>Hello!</html>');
  };

  console.log('I am attached to the page')
```

And the console.log does run when the plugin is removed (I tested it.) I've looked for a way to fix this anywhere I can (on the GitHub documentation, looking at recent tutorials, I looked at various posts on here, etc.), but I haven't been able to find a fix that works for me. I'm running Webpack version 5.48.0, and Webpack CLI 4.7.2